# Changed string info after conversion from NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, afnetworking

I'm converting a NSData object, that is returned from AFHTTPRequestOperation, to NSString:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject
                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

but I realised that the information in responseObject is changed from

```
<39306563 34636638 30353164 34303365 66346531 38643265 37393036 63333866>
```

to

```
90ec4cf8051d403ef4e18d2e7906c38f
```

Help me please...

Comment: are you sure that string isn't the correct response? what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting <39306563 34636638 30353164 34303365 66346531 38643265 37393036 63333866>

Comment: That is simply the output of `NSData description`, not the actual data as a string. You need to clarify what you are really trying to do, what you have, and what you expect.

Comment: <39306563 34636638 30353164 34303365 66346531 38643265 37393036 63333866> is a hexadecimal representation of the data. "90ec4cf8051d403ef4e18d2e7906c38f" is a character string representation. They are the same data. Please refer to CIS101.

Comment: Google "ascii table".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't understand character data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no change of the data, they are two different representations of the same data: hexadecimal and character (ASCII).

39306563 34636638 30353164 34303365 66346531 38643265 37393036 63333866
Is a hexadecimal representation of the data.

90ec4cf8051d403ef4e18d2e7906c38f
Is a character string representation.

They are the same data.

As a partial example:
In the hexadecimal example each two character represents one byte as two hexadecimal digits.
In the character example each character represents one byte as one character.

hex 39 is character 9
hex 30 is character 0
hex 65 is character e
hex 63 is character c
...

Comment: but I want to send back 39306563 34636638 30353164 34303365 66346531 38643265 37393036 63333866 as string

Comment: I don't want to send it's hex representation

Comment: @zontragon - Then why do you want to send back the hex representation?

Comment: If you have data and want a string use create a NSString with: `- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`